# How to post all options in a select element with stringify the text and values?

Tags: javascript, dom, stringify

There is a `select` element that have options created dynamically. I want to post these options text-value pairs via ajax etc...

Is it possible to make them stringify as text-value pairs? Or any suggestions without stringifying text-value pairs.
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @nnnnnn Arun P Johny has answered well. There was no actually written code before. Good coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this if you don't have jQuery

```
function getSelectOptions(id){
    var select = document.getElementById('x');
    var obj = {};
    for(var i=0; i< select.options.length; i++){
        var option = select.options[i];
        obj[option.value] = option.innerHTML;
    }
    return obj;    
}
var opts = getSelectOptions('x');
console.log(opts, JSON.stringify(opts))
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rYwGm/)

With jQuery

```
function getSelectOptions(id){
    var select = $('#' + id);
    var obj = {};
    $('option', select).each(function(i, v){
        var $this = $(this);
        obj[$this.val()] = $this.text();
    });
    return obj;    
}
var opts = getSelectOptions('x');
console.log(opts, JSON.stringify(opts))
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jG5uA/1/)

Comment: Thank you @Arun P Johny , i missed to make an array from options. I got it now. Now i am going to search get the stringified data back at the server with php.

Answer (score 1):

In GET request, you can send them in this form:

```
targetpage.php?option[key1]=value1&option[key2]=value2...
```

The server should understand this as key-value array. To get the option values, use the code Arun P Johny suggests.